# WEB API PUT method is not working and getting HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am not understanding how to fix this can any one please let me know why my put method is not getting executed. I get error

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

in my PUT method. Is there any way to fix using ROUTE attribute to debug my PUT method.

```
public class UserProfessionController : ApiController
{
    //[Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPut]        
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUserProfession([FromUri]string categoryCode)
    {

        try
        {
            int userId = 1;
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(categoryCode))
            {
                var specialitiesRepository = new UserRepository();
                if(specialitiesRepository.UpdateUserProfession(userId, categoryCode) > 0)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
                }

                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Invalid Input Data");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Category Code-" + categoryCode + "For the User " + userId + " is not valid");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(ex.Message),
                ReasonPhrase = "Invalid Input Data"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Status 405 means that the web server doesn't support the method used, in your case PUT. The error doesn't have anything with your code to do. What web server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in web.config system.webServer:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> 
</modules>
```

Comment: You can also remove WebDAV from IIS instead of changing the web.config file

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue - tried the changes to config and IIS regarding removing WebDAV with no success, I tried the following and the issue was resolved.

Remove WebDAV publishing from the IIS install from control panel/program and features - select "turn windows features on/off"

Found this solution at the link below.

https://ignas.me/tech/405-method-not-allowed-iis/

This fixed the issue on both Windows 10 and 7.